# Excel OfficeScript Macro - Moving a Column over to the right

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Hello I am trying to write something that will allow me to copy an entire column and paste it to the right of it. I was able to do this but how can I update it to automatically keep going to the right? I understand I will need to offset but I do not know where to include it. Also would it be possible to remove anything that does not have a formula attached to it? I have included what I have bellow.

This is what I currently have using the record option.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
     let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
     // Paste to range BH:BH on selectedSheet from range BG:BG on selectedSheet
     selectedSheet.getRange("BH:BH").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("BG:BG"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Clear ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents from range BH54:BH57 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("BH54:BH57").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    // Clear ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents from range BH59 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("BH59").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    // Clear ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents from range BH98:BH109 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("BH98:BH109").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    // Clear ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents from range BH132:BH134 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("BH132:BH134").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The code is OfficeScript not VBA. Please update the title and content of OP if you are looking for OfficeScript solution. Do you mean copy column BG to column BI and clear some cells, and so on?

Comment: Sorry I just copied this from the code editor. In reality what I want it to do is that and then after that copy BI to BJ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the source data is in the last column, simplify the code for clearing destination cells.

Please provide details if your data layout is different.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get active worksheet
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the last used column
    let lastColRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getLastColumn();
    // Get the destination range by offsetting one column to the right
    let destRange = lastColRange.getOffsetRange(0, 1);
    // Copy column
    destRange.copyFrom(lastColRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Define a list of row ranges to be cleared
    let rowList = ["54:57", "59:59", "98:109", "132:134"];
    // Loop through and clear the intersection with the destination range
    for (let i = 0; i < rowList.length; i++) {
        let cellRange = selectedSheet.getRange(rowList[i]).getIntersection(destRange);
        if (cellRange) {
            // Clear the contents
            cellRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
        }
    }
    destRange.getEntireColumn().getFormat().autofitColumns();
}
```

---

> Question: if it was possible to copy the entire column over and have it remove anything that doesn't include a formula

Note: *When a user inputs `'=TEST` directly into a cell, the cell will display that text (w/o single quotation mark). However, the code treats any cell starting with '=' as a formula. **Upated code is posted at the end**.*

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get active worksheet
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the last used column
    let lastColRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getLastColumn();
    // Get the destination range by offsetting one column to the right
    let destRange = lastColRange.getOffsetRange(0, 1);
    // Copy column
    destRange.copyFrom(lastColRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    for (let i = 0; i < destRange.getCellCount(); i++) {
        let cellRange = destRange.getRow(i);
        if (!cellRange.getFormula().toString().startsWith("=")) {
            // Clear the contents of non-formula cells
            cellRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
        }
    }
    destRange.getEntireColumn().getFormat().autofitColumns();
}
```

***Update***

A more reliable approach to get all cells which don't have formula

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get active worksheet
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Get the last used column
    let lastColRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getLastColumn();
    // Get the destination range by offsetting one column to the right
    let destRange = lastColRange.getOffsetRange(0, 1);
    // Copy column
    destRange.copyFrom(lastColRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    let constCells = destRange.getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.constants);
    if(constCells){
        constCells.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much! If I wanted to have it auto adjust the column width how would I do that? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I tried this code on another template and the numbers are moved slightly. Would it be  possible to do all the rows and avoid anything with a formula? I tried looking this up and not too sure if it is possible?

Comment: Please clarify `avoid anything with a formula`. Is a formula in source range or dest range?

Comment: the formula is in the source range and I want the formulas to transfer over to the new columns

Comment: `copyFrom` with `RangeCopyType.all` copies everything whic inlcudes formulas.

Comment: The reason I asked is because I am trying to use this on different templates. They are off by a few rows so I was wondering if it was possible to copy the entire column over and have it remove anything that doesn't include a formula.

Comment: I have updated the code to answer your question.

Comment: I have posed a more reliable code.